# Nhibernate mapping - generate "native" says IDs must be manually assigned

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have two tables, one is called QuestionText an the other is called State. When I call SaveOrUpdate() to QuestionText, it saves fine, but when I call SaveOrUpdate() for State I get: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): Entities.State

The mappings are the same for each class.

Any ideas on why nHibernate is saying this for an auto-generated/Identity specified Primary Key for one table but not another... when the mappings are clearly the both the same?

This one works fine:

```
[Serializable()]
[Class(NameType = typeof(QuestionText), Table = "QuestionText", Schema = "eoi")]
public class QuestionText
{
    #region Public Properties
    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Generator(Class = "native")]
    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Id(Name = "QuestionTextID")]
    public virtual int? QuestionTextID { get; set; }

    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property]
    public virtual string QuestionDescription { get; set; }

    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property]
    public virtual string QuestionCategory { get; set; }

    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property]
    public virtual string QuestionDisplayTitle { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

this one doesn't:

```
[Serializable()]
[Class(NameType = typeof(State), Table = "State", Schema = "eoi")]
public class State
{
    #region Public Properties

    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Generator(Class = "native")]
    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Id(Name = "StateID")]
    public virtual int? StateID { get; set; }

    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property]
    public virtual string StateAbbreviation { get; set; }

    [NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Property]
    public virtual string StateName { get; set; }

    #endregion //Public Properties
}//end of class
```

and my save method:

```
internal T Save(T obj)
{
        using (ISession dbSession = EOIDB.GetSession())
        using (ITransaction transaction = dbSession.BeginTransaction())
        {
            try
            {
                dbSession.SaveOrUpdate(obj);
                transaction.Commit();
                return obj;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
                throw ex;
            }
        }
}
```

**Update1:**

I dropped the State table, and tried to insert the data. It gave me the same error as above (set the unique ID). I then dropped the QuestionText table and tried to insert and it gave - {"Invalid object name 'eoi.QuestionText'."}. So does this mean the State object(table) exists twice? somewhere else? or maybe under another schema? I know that State is a keyword in SQLServer so I'm wondering if this could be part of the problem.

Comment: Have you checked that the StateID column is set as an identity?

Comment: Yes, I made sure it has identity set to true. I'll drop and re-create the table. Maybe that will fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out after reading the [doc](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-attributes-tips) and more specifically the line -

- By default, .NET attributes don't keep the order of attributes; so
  you need to set it yourself when the order matter (using the first
  parameter of each attribute); it is highly recommended to set it when
  you have more than one attribute on the same member.

I discovered this by using

```
HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(
typeof(State)), @"C:\temp\EOI.Mappings.xml");
```

and then looking at what the file mappings were. The 'Generator' element was never created. This is because the parent node was being created after the child (generator) and this caused the 'id' element to not have a 'generator' child element. So I changed my attributes (see below) and it started working

```
[NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Id(0,Name = "StateID",Column="StateID")]
[NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.Generator(1,Class="native")]
public virtual int? StateID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try enclosing the `Table="State"` with square brackets: `Table="[State]"`. It might be your DB throwing up with the reserved keyword.